# Passing enum class name though @Input

Tags: angular, input, enums

I don't know if that's possible with angular but I want to pass in argument in my component a class type. 
The goal is to construct a select with my enum. But the enum is different from all parents.

```
    public class HomeType{
        HOUSE, BUILDING
    }

    public class RoomType {
        KITCHEN, BEDROOM
    }

    @Component({
        selector: 'children',
        templateUrl: './chlidren.component.html'
    })
    export class childrenComponent {

       _enum: any;

       @Input('class')
       set class (clazz: any) {
           this._enum = Object.keys(clazz)
                          .map(key => ({ value:definition[key], title: key }))
           // clazz should be of type EnumType
       }
    }


// in parent html

    ...
    <children [class]="HomeType"></children>
    ...
    <children [class]="RoomType"></children>
```

If you have any idea of doing something similar, please help me.

thanks

Comment: Is there any relationship between the enums `HomeType` and `RoomType`?

Comment: ++ Where is the enum in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Well I dont know why you want to do that, but probably the way to do it would be like this, If I understood you correctly

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
export enum HomeType {
  HOUSE = "HOUSE",
  BUILDING = "BUILDING"
}

export enum RoomType {
  KITCHEN = "KITCHEN",
  BEDROOM = "BEDROOM"
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  test: RoomType | HomeType = HomeType.HOUSE;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.test == RoomType.KITCHEN ? 'Kitcken' : 'Not a Kitchen :)'
  }
}
```

PS. But as you see if you have same key in both enum you will have a problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bywsre

Comment: I edited my question, I think it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not what I'm looking for. I find a workaround. I did something static and not dynamic. Thank you for your time